# Install Blackboard Auto Signon building block

Tags: java, autologin, blackboard, buildingblocks

I am creating an application to autologin the blackboard user. I have researched for this a lot, and I came to know that we need an "Auto Signon" building block inside our Blackboard Learn and proceed with some settings.

Can anyone help me to understand how it is done? As I cannot find any link from where I could download it.

I took help from this [link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjl_b60mJ_MAhUEspQKHV3yAJgQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fprojects.oscelot.org%2Fgf%2Fdownload%2Ffrsrelease%2F749%2F4758%2FAutoSignon_SSO_Admin_Guide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFiXNnG4BkxMLq4PVqUfv6YKB_Bkg&bvm=bv.119967911,d.dGo&cad=rja).

Comment: Minor edits to clearly separate the plugin name and the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackboard plugins are called "Building Block". So, you need to install a plugin named "Auto SignOn".

You need to download and install it through the Blackboard admin dashboard. I presume you have an access to your Bb installation's admin panel, right?

If you have not installed any building blocks yet, then you can learn more about them and how to install them in [Bb's developers resources](https://behind.blackboard.com/).

You need a "Behind the Blackboard" account to access this resources. The procurement or IT department should have it or might help you create one.

Comment: yes, I have access to "behind the blackboard " account as well as Blackboard admin dashboard. I had searched there previously, I didn't find any building block named "AutoSignon". Can you send me the link where this is available?

Comment: Here is a [how-to](http://library.blackboard.com/ref/af0b9ce2-a44e-4bf9-a3e0-e54102fa592f/Content/_admin_app_system/admin_app_building_blocks_install.htm) and here is [download link](http://projects.oscelot.org/gf/project/autosignon/frs/).

Comment: Thank you so much.. I was stuck into this for a very long time.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is also an example of using it in Java. https://github.com/cjazinski/BbAuthentication - It follows along with the example found in the docs.